# Automated sorting of files into folders using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to put a macro together to sort files into folders based on a filename. I am locked into using VBA due to the system we are on.

For example sorting just the excel documents from below present in C:\ :

```
123DE.xls
124DE.xls
125DE.xls
124.doc
123.csv
```

into the following folder paths:

```
C:\Data\123\Data Extract
C:\Data\124\Data Extract
C:\Data\125\Data Extract
```

The folders are already created, and as in the example are named after the first x characters of the file. Batches of 5000+ files will need to be sorted into over 5000 folders so im trying to avoid coding for each filename

I am pretty new to VBA, so any guidance would be much appreciated. So far I have managed to move all the excel files into a single folder, but am unsure how to progress.

```
Sub MoveFile()

Dim strFolderA As String
Dim strFolderB As String
Dim strFile as String

strFolderA = "\\vs2-alpfc\omgusers7\58129\G Test\"
strFolderb = "\\vs2-alpfc\omgusers7\58129\G Test\1a\"
strFile = Dir(strFolderA & "*.xlsx*")

Do While Len(strFile) >0
    Name StrFolderA & strFile As strFolderB & strFile
    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Greg

EDIT

```
Sub MoveFile()

Dim strFolderA As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim AccNo As String

strFolderA = "\\vs2-alpfc7\omgUSERS7\58129\G Test\"

strFile = Dir(strFolderA & "*.xlsx*")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0

AccNo = Left(strFile, 2)

    Name strFolderA & strFile As strFolderA & "\" & AccNo & "\Data Extract\" & strFile

    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks folks, are a few more bits and pieces i want to add, but functionality is there!

Comment: What code have you put together so far?

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Updated with my current code there - first real post so bear with me!

Comment: Consider powershell or cmd to do this batch operation

Comment: Are all those 5000+ files in same folder?

Comment: I dint have access to powershell or the CMD - the 5k files are in the base folder (for examples sake the C:\) all subfolders are in that same drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub DivideFiles()
Const SourceDir = "C:\"  'where your files are
Const topdir = "\\vs2-alpfc\omgusers7\58129\G Test\"

Dim s As String
Dim x As String
s = Dir(SourceDir & "\*.xls?")
Do
x = Left(s, 3) 'I assume we're splitting by first three chars

Name SourceDir & s As topdir & s & "\" & s

Loop Until s = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is deriving the new fullpathname from the file name to use as the `newpathname` argument of the `Name` function.

If all of your files end with `DE.XLS*` you can do something like:

```
NewPathName = C:\Data\ & Split(strFile, "DE")(0) & "\Data Extract\" & strFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Filesystem object (tools > references > microsoft scripting runtime

This does a copy first then delete. You can comment out delete line and check copy is safely performed.

If on Mac replace "\" with `Application.PathSeparator`.

Based on assumption, as you stated, that folders already exist.

```
 Option Explicit

Sub FileAway()

    Dim fileNames As Collection
    Set fileNames = New Collection

    With fileNames
        .Add "123DE.xls"
        .Add "124DE.xls"
        .Add "125DE.xls"
        .Add "124.doc"
        .Add "123.csv"
    End With

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject                  'tools > references > scripting runtime
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sourcePath As String
    sourcePath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop"      'where files currently are

    For i = 1 To fileNames.Count

        If Not fso.FileExists("C:\Data\" & Left$(fileNames(i), 3) & "\Data Extract\" & fileNames(i)) Then

            fso.CopyFile (sourcePath & "\" & fileNames(i)), _
            "C:\Data\" & Left$(fileNames(i), 3) & "\Data Extract\", True

            fso.DeleteFile (sourcePath & "\" & fileNames(i))
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```